# Making a long vector(coloumn Matrix) using small arrays

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make one vector(feature vector) which contains array elements.

Suppose I have an array `arr1` of  size `nx1` in first iteration. I have to add this array elements to the `CvMat` matrix `featureVect` of size, `2*n x 1`.

In next iteration I have an array `arr2` of size `nx1`, and now I have to add this array to `featureVect` from row `n+1` to `2*n` (using a one-based index)

Suppose I have

```
int arr1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int arr2[4] = {5, 6, 7, 8};

CvMat *featureVect;
```

Now I want the result to look like this (where `featureVect` is a one column matrix)

```
featureVect = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};// featureVect size is 8x1;
```

Comment: Sorry but what's your question? Also please post some code.

Comment: Hi CharlesB, can give me some Idea about this question

Comment: @CharlesB: Concatenation of `int` arrays into a `CvMat` object (a matrix in the OpenCV library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C++ with OpenCV I would recommend the `Mat` class. Then,

```
Mat featureVect(8,1,CV_32S); //CV_32s <=> int (32-bit signed integer)
const int n = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
{
   featureVect.at<int>(i,0)     = arr1[i];
   featureVect.at<int>(i+n,0) = arr2[i];
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: ThanQ Jacob, It is working fine

Comment: Hi, Jacob is there any way to directly assign the array to Column matrix instead of using `for` loop, to reduce the **complexity** of the program